# I get NoClassDefFoundError on my external dependency when running my fat jar using AdoptJDK11. What is wrong?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX 11/13 application built with JDK 11. The requirement users should not need to download java in order to use the JavaFX application. In addition, I am also using an external jar which I have defined as an external dependency.

The other specs of my JavaFX11 Projects are below:

- AdoptJDK version: 11
- JavaFX version: 13
- Has external dependency which is provided manually (via mail) by third party vendor. No Maven repo url.
- Build tool: Maven

I have tried creating a fat jar but I get a NoClassDefFoundError on the external jar I'm using. And it seems that users would need to install Java on their machine. Should I use a different JDK with java packaging supported natively?

The steps I did to package my application is as follows:

1. I defined the external dependency on my pom file as seen below:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.my.toolkit</groupId>
       <artifactId>mytoolkit</artifactId>
       <version>8.1.0</version>
       <scope>system</scope>
       <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/libs/mytoolkit.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Added the dependency in the libs folder
   [image]
3. I compiled my javafx project with the command: `mvn package`
4. Then, I run my myapp jar with the command: `java -jar myapp.jar`
   [image]

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` means that your application was unable to locate and load a class (Likely your external jar dependency). Please edit your question to show the full error (All 10+ lines) and show how are trying to load that dependency, and also the file structure of the compiled application (where are you placing the dependency relative to your main/fat jar).

Comment: @sorifiend done, please see above.

Comment: no screenshots of text please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already have the folder structure and the dependency is there, and it doesn't work. So I added a Manifest file with the class paths, and copied the dependencies to the same directory as my main jar, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by where you place your external dependency. The following line tells your jar where to look for your external dependency:

```
<systemPath>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/libs/enttoolkit.jar</systemPath>
```

Note how it is looking in the basedir (the place where your main application jar is) then it is looking for a "src" folder which contains a folder named "main" which contains a folder named "resources" .... which contains a jar named "enttoolkit.jar".

You can solve this several ways, first, you can create the folder structure specified in your dependency, or two you can fix the dependency path to look directly in the same directory as your main jar or some other path pointing to exactly where you place the `enttoolkit.jar` file:

```
<systemPath>${pom.basedir}/enttoolkit.jar</systemPath>
```

Of if it was in a libs folder instead of the same folder as your fat jar:

```
<systemPath>${pom.basedir}/libs/enttoolkit.jar</systemPath>
```

Or thirdly you could use a classloader do this in code when your application starts rather than relying on your pom file.